# Return 6 previous Month select last month

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemcode, 
                itemdescription, 
                unitofmeasure, 
                Sum([current]) AS [Ending Balance] 
WHERE  transactiondate >= Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, 
                                         Dateadd(m, -6, '2019-01-31' 
                                         )), 0)
```

Comment: You are missing a `from` clause in your query.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with your expected results

Comment: but i need to show  the last month records July-Dec 2018

Comment: am select the January 2019  but i need to 6 month result to get averages July-Dec 2018 but still show transaction of January 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing FROM and GROUP BY clause and the Date Diff (Six Mont considering End Date = '2019-01-31') can be calculated as shown in the below script-

```
SELECT
itemcode, 
itemdescription, 
unitofmeasure, 
Sum([current]) AS [Ending Balance] 
FROM <your_table> -- FROM is missing. Please add appropriate table name
WHERE  transactiondate Between 
    DATEADD(month, -6, '2019-01-31') 
    AND '2019-01-31'  
GROUP BY itemcode,itemdescription,unitofmeasure
-- GROUP BY is required as you applied Aggregation on column [current]
```

If you wants only records from the 6th Previous month, WHERE condition will be as below-

```
WHERE  YEAR(transactiondate) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -6, '2019-01-31'))
AND MONTH(transactiondate) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -6, '2019-01-31'))
```

For getting results from last 6 month, WHERE will be as below-

```
WHERE transactiondate BETWEEN
CAST(LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(MM,-6,CAST('2019-01-31' AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR),7) + '-01' AS DATE)
AND
DATEADD(DD,-1,CAST(CAST(LEFT(CAST(CAST('2019-01-31' AS DATE) AS VARCHAR),7) + '-01' AS DATE) AS DATE))
-- This is basically: transactiondate BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

Comment: but i need to show  the last month records July-Dec 2018

Comment: Only from 6th month from the inserted date? If the input date is '2019-02-28' then only records from August-2018?

Comment: Thanks mkRabbani  but are client  they select on '2019-01-31' then result July-Dec 2018 its that why i need to result in 6 month.

Comment: @BenedictCaoili please check the new WHERE part added below in the answer.

Comment: Sir my a have another question

Comment: Yes please.. :)

Comment: sum(([current])/6) AS [Ending Balance]  this a right to get averages by 6 months

Comment: Yes, just use ([current])/6.0

Comment: To get it in each row, need to use sum([current])/6.0